# Unity3D or Android Studio for a android 2D game?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, unity-game-engine

I had an idea for a 2D incremental-game (such as cookie clicker) but i dont know whats the best way to do it. At first i was thinking about Android Studio since incremental-games are simple and UI-like, but after some research i have came to think that it would be easier with Unity3D.
I'm not new at programming (Nowadays im programming in C and python mostly but last year i was studying java) but i've never done anything better than a HelloWorld android app.

Comment: You are comparing a game engine to an IDE.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Android studio is best for apps that use [Activities](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) (i.e. apps like the [YouTube App](http://lh3.ggpht.com/-2JsVPFP8LuU/UhMOHciWabI/AAAAAAAAjBg/Y3tFoqhyfLE/s1600/Screenshot_2013-08-20-08-34-22.png) and the [FotMob App](http://cdn4.aptoide.com/imgs/4/4/6/4464de095cbaf1719764358209c13154_screen_384x640.png)). These apps are structured very similarly. They have an [App Bar](http://developer.android.com/training/appbar/index.html) that the user uses to navigate to different "pages" to for their desired information.

However, for apps like [Cookie Clicker](http://content.chupamobile.com/user-upload2/product-image-screenshot/LJfztyLfxOFpX0Ayys6nw49I_4_screen568x568.jpeg) or [Candy Crush](http://coolappsman.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/Screenshot_2013-01-25-02-39-311.png), you can see they do not follow the same template. Instead, both games have their own graphics engines developed by the studios or some third party. So, unless you want to make your own graphics engine, you should definitely use Unity.

Answer (score 2):

Did you try with libGDX? You don't need an emulator and is quite similar to Java. You have to check a new documentation but you will do anyway with Unity.

Comment: i agree. if your game is going to be simple and mostly support android, use libgdx.